# How do I find a child's parent through a has_one association in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to, has-one

Say I have the following models:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I'd like to retrive the parent through the child, but doing the following fails:
I find the model in the following way through a controller

```
@child = Child.find(params[:child_id])
```

(Not sure if this is relevant, but since I'm using shallow routing, the parent_id is not available in the URL)

In my view, I'd like to retrieve the child's parent like this:

```
@child.parent
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

---

Update: my example (when I decided to start a new app and create it) actually ran perfectly.
In my actual app, I forgot to include `belongs_to :parent` in the child's model. How silly of me. Thanks for taking the time to comment and answer, guys. Next time I'll look more carefully before posting a question here.

Comment: `@child.parent` should work; what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that I wasn't looking closely enough. See update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's exactly how you do it.

The fact that it's not working suggests there's some underlying issue preventing `@child` from having a parent.

First off, check that the table for `Child` has a foreign key. The foreign key column (in this case `parent_id`) should always be on the model that has the `belongs_to` association.

Secondly, check that the child you're fetching actually has a parent. This means that the foreign key (`parent_id`) should not be nil. If it has a numeric value, check that the table for `Parent` has a record with the same value as the foreign_key in `Child`.

You can also use the Rails console (`rails console` from your application directory) to double-check associations. Do `Child.first.parent` and see what's going on. Of course, you can start using variations such as `Parent.first.child` or `Child.find(123).parent` as well, but you can't use `params`.